# TypeScript and inheritance

Tags: typescript

I need a little help with `TypeScript`. How to do <strike>extension methods</strike> inheritance?

Lets say we have a class named `MyClass` with only one method `Method1()`:

```
class MyClass {
   constructor () { }

   public Method1(): void {
   }
}
```

Now I want to make a sub class that adds a new method named `Method2()`:

```
class MyClassExtension {
   public Method2(): void {
   }
}
```

When I have interfaces I can do this by declaring a new interface with the same name:

```
interface MyInterface {
   Method1(): void;
}

interface MyInterface {
   Method2(): void;
}

var x: MyInterface;
x.Method1(); // ok
x.Method2(); // ok
```

But I don't know how to do this for classes:/ Can any1 help me, please?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Declaring two classes with the same name won't work?

Comment: typescript doesn't have "Extension methods" - you're confusing it with c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your response to JohnnyHK's answer, can you do something like the following?

If your existing jquery.d.ts looks something like this:

```
interface JQuery {
    //...OTHER MEMBERS IN JQUERY
    addClass(classNames: string): JQuery;
    addClass(func: (index: any, currentClass: any) => JQuery);

    attr(attributeName: string): string;
    attr(attributeName: string, value: any): JQuery;
    //...OTHER MEMBERS IN JQUERY
}

interface JQueryStatic {
    //...OTHER MEMBERS IN JQUERY
    parent(selector?: string): JQuery;

    parents(selector?: string): JQuery;

    parentsUntil(selector?: string, filter?: string): JQuery;
    parentsUntil(element?: Element, filter?: string): JQuery;
    //...OTHER MEMBERS IN JQUERY
}


declare var jQuery: JQueryStatic;
declare var $: JQueryStatic;
```

Then all you would need to do in your code somewhere is define your extension methods, for example:

**file1.ts**

```
///<reference path='jquery.d.ts'/>
interface JQuery {
    myNewExtensionMethod() : string;
}
interface JQueryStatic {
    myNewExtensionMethod() : string;
}

jQuery.myNewExtensionMethod = () => {
    return "11";
}

$.myNewExtensionMethod = () => {
    return "11";
}
```

And then use them:

**file2.ts**

```
///<reference path='file1.ts'/>
var result = $.myNewExtensionMethod();
```

Answer (score 10):

This is standard class inheritance, so you can do it like this:

```
class MyClassExtension extends MyClass {
   public Method2(): void {
   }
}
```

In your `interface` example, you're not declaring a new interface with the same name, you're splitting the `MyInterface` definition across two partial definitions.  Interface definitions are open-ended but classes are not.

Comment: Worth noting that this also works for interfaces, and is a clearer way (IMO) of expressing interface inheritance.

Comment: I wrote my post a little bad:S What I want? I have `JQuery` lib in `TS`. Now I want to add some extension methods into `JQuery` and `JQueryStatic` objects. And I want them to be available after `.` (dot): `$.myNewExtensionMethod()`.

Comment: JQuery is only exposed as an `interface`, you can only `extend` other classes so you'd have to use @stopyoukid's option in that case.